# Can I retrieve Data from two Databases?

Tags: asp.net, sql-server-2008, c#-4.0

I want to retrieve some data to use it in my grid, but the problem is my database design contains two databases.

So, can I retrieve data from more than database, to use it at one grid ?

I use ASP.Net, C#.Net 4, Microsoft SQL Server 2008 R2

Answer (score 0):

SQL Server knows 4 part object names. The first part is the (linked) server name. The second part is the database name. third and fourth are schema and object name.

Assuming your databases are on the same server you can just write a query like:

```
SELECT * 
FROM Database1.dbo.Table1 t1 
JOIN Database2.dbo.Table2 t2 
ON t1.column = t2.column;
```

Answer (score 0):

There are several ways depending on your architecture.
If your databases are deployed in the same machine you can select data from two different databases like this:

```
SELECT a.userID, b.usersFirstName, b.usersLastName  
FROM databaseA.dbo.TableA a 
inner join database B.dbo.TableB b  ON a.userID=b.userID
```

Of course you should have permission in both databases.
You can check here for more information: http://forums.asp.net/t/1254974.aspx/1